# How to find number of keys with certain values in a deep Javascript object?

Tags: javascript

I have the following deep Javascript object, how do I find the number of '`type`' keys which have a value of '`foo`' ?

```
{
    ...
    blocks: [{
        items: [{
            type: "foo"
        },
        {
            type: "subBlock",
            items: [{
                type: "foo"
            }]
        }]
    },
    {
        items: [{
            type: "foo"
        },
        {
            type: "foo"
        }]
    }]
    ...
}
```

Comment: `forEach` & `Object.keys` might help you

Comment: You will have to iterate through the object and for each key assert whether it has the value `"foo"`

Answer (score 0):

You can create recursive function that will loop your data structure and return total count.

```js
var obj = {
  blocks: [{
    items: [{
      type: "foo"
    }, {
      type: "subBlock",
      items: [{
        type: "foo"
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    items: [{
      type: "foo"
    }, {
      type: "foo"
    }]
  }]
}

function countFoo(data) {
  var result = 0;
  if (typeof data == 'object' && !Array.isArray(data)) {
    Object.keys(data).forEach(function(e) {
      if (e == 'type' && data[e] == 'foo') {
        result++;
      } else if (typeof data[e] == 'object') {
        result += countFoo(data[e]);
      }
    })
  } else if (Array.isArray(data)) {
    data.forEach(function(e) {
      if (typeof e == 'object') {
        result += countFoo(e);
      }
    })
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(countFoo(obj))
```